# Connect Strongswan/VPN-Client (Debian) to IPSec/L2TP Server (Windows 2012) - AUTHENTIFICATION_FAILED

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, debian-stretch, strongswan

I am trying to connect my Debian Stretch box with a network running Windows-Only machines. There is a node there that acts as a VPN Server that runs Windows Server 2012R2. I am able to connect to it via L2TP VPN from both my Windows and my Mac machine, so even though I don't like the setup - it seems to be working. It's dumb easy configured without certs with a simple PSK. But all my many hours of trying to get it connected with a Debian box failed today :( I have tried every possible config modifications I found on the web... Here is the shortest one I am trying now getting always the same error at the end (PSK is correct):

ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
conn %default
    authby=secret
conn intp
    left=%any
    leftfirewall=no
    right=server_hostname
    rightfirewall=yes
    type=tunnel
    auto=add
```

ipsec.secrets

```
include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.secrets.inc
: PSK VALID_PSK
```

ipsec up intp

```
initiating IKE_SA intp[1] to 194.84.28.242
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 144.76.196.175[500] to 194.84.28.242[500] (1300 bytes)
received packet: from 194.84.28.242[500] to 144.76.196.175[500] (38 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
peer didn't accept DH group MODP_3072, it requested MODP_1024
initiating IKE_SA intp[1] to 194.84.28.242
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 144.76.196.175[500] to 194.84.28.242[500] (1044 bytes)
received packet: from 194.84.28.242[500] to 144.76.196.175[500] (360 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V V ]
received MS NT5 ISAKMPOAKLEY v9 vendor ID
received MS-Negotiation Discovery Capable vendor ID
remote host is behind NAT
no IDi configured, fall back on IP address
authentication of '144.76.196.175' (myself) with pre-shared key
establishing CHILD_SA intp
generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) ]
sending packet: from 144.76.196.175[4500] to 194.84.28.242[4500] (412 bytes)
received packet: from 194.84.28.242[4500] to 144.76.196.175[4500] (68 bytes)
parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error
establishing connection 'intp' failed
```

Please help :)

Comment: L2TP is usually used with IKEv1, however, you are connecting with IKEv2. To connect with IKEv1 set _keyexchange=ikev1_ (you'll need to change other stuff too, e.g. the traffic selectors with _left|rightsubnet_). However, since the server does respond to IKEv2 requests you might want to consider using that if the server administrator can provide you with valid credentials as it is the far superior protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much! You pointed me exactly to the right direction!